# How to prove that for $a_k>0$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1} +a_{k+2}}\ge \frac{n}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

For $k=1,2,\dots,n$  and $a_k>0$ let $a_{n+1}=a_1, a_{n+2}= a_2$ I want to prove that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1} +a_{k+2}}\ge \frac{n}{4}.$$

Context: I saw this problem on my problem book and after an hour of thinking I couldn't get to anything useful.
I tried to use AM-HM inequality and Cauchy's inequality but this lead to nothing.

---

**Also** What values of $a_k$ achieves $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1} +a_{k+2}}= \frac{n}{4}$?

In these type of equation it is usually when $a_k$ is a constant sequence (like Cauchy's inequality when $a_k=b_k$ and AM-GM-HM inequality  when $a_k$ is a constant sequence).

Comment: For $n=3$ this just a weakened version of Nesbitt's inequality.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Or for general $n$ a weakened version of Shapiro's inequality.

Comment: Answer 1.9, page 7 of this [file](https://www.turgor.ru/lktg/2010/5/5-1en.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic proof of this weakened Shapiro inequality. Let $x_1$ be the maximum of $a_i,$ $i=1,…,n$. Let $x_2$ be the maximum of the two numbers following $x_1$ in the sequence $\{a_i\}$. Then let $x_3$ be the maximum of the two numbers following $x_2$ and so on. This process will end up back in $x_1$. Then we can say that the LHS of your inequality is greater or equal to

$$\frac{x_1}{2x_2}+ \frac{x_2}{2x_3}+\dots+ \frac{x_m}{2x_1}$$

which is obviously (due to AM-GM) $\geq m/2 \geq n/4$.

Comment: +1, That's clever!